# how to customize CMenu widget in Yii

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii, cmenu

How can I set CMenu to dropdown in Yii framework project to display like what is in http://www.yiiframework.com/ website.

Comment: something like this: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/93/using-the-jqueryslidemenu-plugin-with-cmenu/?

Comment: Stu, that url gives me error: The system is unable to find the requested action "93".

Comment: weird, how about this: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/211/creating-a-css3-drop-down-menu-using-cmenu/

Comment: would you send it as an answer. I want to accept it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a good demo here: [Creating a CSS Driven Drop Down Menu using CMenu](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/211/creating-a-css3-drop-down-menu-using-cmenu/) about creating a nice dropdown menu using CMenu.